# Inverting a function of 3 variables

Tags: complex-analysis, inverse, stereographic-projections

We can define a stereographic projection by

$$f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\frac{x_1+ix_2}{1-x_3}$$

It is said the inverse of f can be computed to receive the general point where the line intersects the sphere. However I am struggling to understand how to find the inverse of a 3 variable function.

Comment: It isn't fully a 3-variable function. It is a function that takes a point on the unit sphere (apart from the north pole) as input and yields a point in the plane. Those points on the sphere just happen to be somewhat easy to describe using three coordinates. You are asked to take an arbitrary point in the plane and find the corresponding point on the unit sphere.

Comment: @Arthur the question asks me to the invert the formula, and gives me a hint to first solve for x3, then to get x1 and x2. I am able to find the corresponding point on the unit sphere through other means, but my question is how can I compute the inverse of this particular formula?

Answer (score 1):

Let $$\frac{x_1+ix_2}{1-x_3}=a+ib$$
Then $$x_1+ix_2=(1-x_3)(a+ib)$$ Hence $$1=x_1^2+x^2_2+x_3^2=(a^2+b^2)(1-x_3)^2+x_3^2$$ which implies $$(a^2+b^2)(1-x_3)=1+x_3.$$ Now we can solve for $x_3.$